# bupaR function/s interpretation

Tags: r, bupar

I'm trying to work out a bit of code someone has given me. If someone could help explain whats going on I'd be grateful.

```
data %>% process_map(type_nodes =  processmapR::frequency("relative_case"),type_edges = processmapR::performance(mean, units = "hours"))
```

I haven't been allowed to share the raw data for this graph unfortunately.

I have tried adding up the times for a case to to transition between Start and Node 1 or Node 2 or Node 3 to see if its an average value, but it doesn't appear to be.

From bupaR doco:

"relative_case - percentage of cases the activity occurs in."
But I would have expected a  %  figure ( like 0.4 ), but instead have whole numbers. And if it is a percentage displayed in whole numbers, how do you find the enumerator?

I've spent hours on this and don't seem to have got any further. The doco unfortunately is a bit sparse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **general** way I use to find out about an unknown function.

First, try to figure out which package it came from. I did so like this:

```r
library(collidr)
library(tidyverse)

collidr::CRANdf %>%
  filter(function_names == "process_map")

#  package_names function_names
#  processmapR    process_map
```

but you could try googling as well.

Then, go to the package's [CRAN page](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/processmapR/index.html) (google should bring that up easily), and take a look at it's [manual](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/processmapR/processmapR.pdf#page=14) - that will contain documentation for the each function in the package.

In the case of the function you're looking at, there's several pages of documentation on that one function (starting on page 14 of the manual). I like to look at the `Description` field:

> A function for creating a process map of an event log.

And the `Examples` field gives an example you can run and see what the function does.